# Pandas: Create dataframe of rows where the median of a groupby object column is above a threshold

Tags: python, pandas

I've got a dataframe with columns `gene_name`, `sample_name`, `value`, and `e_id`. I want to create a dataframe containing only the rows where the median `value` of all the `sample_name` in a `gene_name` is above a threshold.

E.g. if I have the following dataframe:

```
 e_id gene_name sample_name  value
    1     gene1     sample1     10
    2     gene1     sample1     21
    3     gene1     sample1     31
    4     gene2     sample1     40
    5     gene2     sample1     50
    6     gene2     sample1     60
    2     gene1     sample2     11
    3     gene1     sample2     22
    1     gene1     sample2     32
    5     gene2     sample2     41
    6     gene2     sample2     51
    4     gene2     sample2     61
    3     gene1     sample3     12
    1     gene1     sample3     23
    2     gene1     sample3     33
    6     gene2     sample3     42
    4     gene2     sample3     52
    5     gene2     sample3     62
    1     gene1     sample4     13
    2     gene1     sample4     24
    3     gene1     sample4     34
    4     gene2     sample4     43
    5     gene2     sample4     53
    6     gene2     sample4     63
```

where the medians are:

```
gene_name  sample_name
gene1      sample1        21
           sample2        22
           sample3        23
           sample4        24
gene2      sample1        50
           sample2        51
           sample3        52
           sample4        53
```

a threshold of 22 should yield a dataframe containing only the entries with `gene2`, since not all samples in `gene1` have medians above 22. The result should look like this:

```
 e_id gene_name sample_name  value
    4     gene2     sample1     40
    5     gene2     sample1     50
    6     gene2     sample1     60
    5     gene2     sample2     41
    6     gene2     sample2     51
    4     gene2     sample2     61
    6     gene2     sample3     42
    4     gene2     sample3     52
    5     gene2     sample3     62
    4     gene2     sample4     43
    5     gene2     sample4     53
    6     gene2     sample4     63
```

I've found the medians using `groupby`:

```
df.groupby(["gene_name", "sample_name"])["value"].median()
```

but I haven't been able to proceed from here. Thanks!

**Edit**: To clarify, ALL samples in a gene must have values over the threshold

Comment: Try this `df1 = df.groupby(['gene_name','sample_name']).median().reset_index()` and then `df1[df1.value > 22]`, please let me know if this would get your desired result.

Comment: @Abbas, this still does not consider all samples in a gene being above the threshold, but it's a start, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let `cond` be a boolean dataframe showing which medians are above threshold:

```
cond = df.groupby(["gene_name", "sample_name"])["value"].median() >= 22
```

We can `groupby` again to find out which genes have all medians above threshold:

```
cond.groupby(level=0).all()
```

Output:

```
gene_name
gene1    False
gene2     True
dtype: bool
```

You can use this to filter the original dataframe. The first step is to extract the list of gene names that fill the condition. There can be more elegant ways, but I used this:

```
s = cond.groupby(level=0).all()
gene_list = s[s.values].index.tolist()
```

Now it's easy to filter the original dataframe:

```
df[df.gene_name.isin(gene_list)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using filter:

```
threshold = 22
df.groupby(["gene_name", "sample_name"]).filter(lambda x: x['value'].median() > threshold)
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't require **all** samples to have medians above the threshold. I've updated my question to clarify